# Modular PyTests

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to create reusable PyTest functions that pass in a tuple of objects inside a class. At the moment, I've written about 12 tests to assert certain conditions, most notably, whether an object is None, object is not None, Object is a str instance and Object is not a str instance. So I was thinking as 12 functions to pretty much do the exact same thing, I could whittle that number down to 4 re-usable functions using `@pytest.mark.paramtrize`.

Finally, to the core of the problem. I create a dataset like the following and pass the dataset to the paramtrize function. In the example below, I've tried to pass the fixture return object, and I've also tried to call the fixture directly using `()`, which results in a warning about calling fixtures directly.

**Code**

```
def setup_nifExplorer():
    '''Returns a Nif Explorer Instance'''        
    explorer = NifExplorer()

    explorer.BlockType = NifFormat.NiNode
    explorer.ResultPath = None
    explorer.SearchPath = None    
    
    return explorer   

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup_nifExplorer")
class TestNifExplorer:

    @pytest.mark.paramtrize('object', [setup_nifExplorer.BlockType, setup_nifExplorer.SearchPath, setup_nifExplorer.ResultPath])
    def test_Object_Is_None(self, object):
        assert object != None

    def test_Class_Is_None(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert setup_nifExplorer == None

    def test_BlockType_Not_None(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert setup_nifExplorer.BlockType != None

    def test_BlockType_Is_None(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert setup_nifExplorer.BlockType == None

    def test_BlockType_Is_String(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert isinstance(setup_nifExplorer.BlockType, str)

    def test_BlockType_Not_String(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert not isinstance(setup_nifExplorer.BlockType, str)   
        
    def test_SearchPath_Not_None(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert setup_nifExplorer.SearchPath != None
    
    def test_SearchPath_Is_None(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert setup_nifExplorer.SearchPath == None
    
    def test_SearchPath_Is_String(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert isinstance(setup_nifExplorer.SearchPath, str)
  
    def test_SearchPath_Not_String(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert not isinstance(setup_nifExplorer.SearchPath, str)

    def test_SearchPath_Directory_Does_Exist(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert os.path.exists(setup_nifExplorer.SearchPath) == True

    def test_SearchPath_Directory_Does_Not_Exist(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        if setup_nifExplorer.SearchPath == None or os.path.exists(setup_nifExplorer.SearchPath) == False:
            assert True

    def test_ResultPath_Not_None(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert setup_nifExplorer.ResultPath != None
    
    def test_ResultPath_Is_None(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert setup_nifExplorer.ResultPath == None
    
    def test_ResultPath_Is_String(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert isinstance(setup_nifExplorer.ResultPath, str)
  
    def test_ResultPath_Not_String(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert not isinstance(setup_nifExplorer.ResultPath, str)
        
    def test_ResultPath_Directory_Does_Exist(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert os.path.exists(setup_nifExplorer.ResultPath) == True

    def test_ResultPath_Directory_Does_Not_Exist(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        if setup_nifExplorer.ResultPath == None or os.path.exists(setup_nifExplorer.ResultPath) == False:
            assert True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main()
```

**What I've tried:**
Amongst a lot of googling, I've come across an open issue on GitHub as a feature request, which still remains open. The issue was raised back in 2013. https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349

Don't get me wrong, the other tests work, I'm just trying to reduce the number of unnecessary functions.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community along with Python `3.9.1` and PyTest `6.2.1`.

**Edit 1**

```
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('funcs', [SearchPath_None, ResultPath_None, BlockType_None])
    def test_NifExplorer_Variables_None(self, setup_nifExplorer, funcs):
        funcs(self,setup_nifExplorer)

    def SearchPath_None(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert setup_nifExplorer.SearchPath == None

    def ResultPath_None(self, setup_nifExlorer):
        assert setup_nifExlorer.ResultPath == None

    def BlockType_None(self, setup_nifExplorer):
        assert setup_nifExplorer.BlockType == None
```

Comment: Right now you're trying to access attributes on the fixture function itself, which doesn't make sense, and you have a typo in the name of the method (param**e**trize). But if you call it with a list of three values, your test runs three times - I think you want more than that. Typically you'd group parametrised tests such that all the tests in the group are asserting the same thing, otherwise the test ends up full of conditional logic.

Comment: @jonrsharpe When you refer to grouping tests together, are you referring to something like **Edit 1**? If not, could you clarify please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that passing `@pytest.fixture` return data into `@pytest.mark.parametrize` is not possible at this point.

There is an open Github issue found here: [Using fixtures in pytest.mark.parametrize #349](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349)

I have moved on from this idea until it can adequately be implemented with ease.